# variables not defined in if statements for change counting program

Tags: python

I'm making a change counter and I'm having trouble printing the percentage for a grade, whenever I run the program I can enter as many inputs as I want, however, when I type done, which is supposed to terminate the program and leave the user with the percentage and letter grade, it just ends the program. If I could get any advice it would be greatly appreciated.
here's my code:

```
grade=""
total=0
count=1
scores=''

while scores != 'done':
    scores=input("Enter Homework score: ")
    if scores.isdigit():
        numeric=int(scores)
        percentage=(numeric*10/count)
    elif percentage >= 92 and percentage < 100:
        letter = 'A'
    elif percentage >= 87 and percentage < 92:
        letter = 'B+'
    elif percentage >= 80 and percentage < 87:
        letter = 'B'
    elif percentage >=77 and percentage < 80:
        letter = 'C+'
    elif percentage >=70 and percentage < 77:
        letter = 'C'
    elif percentage >= 67 and percentage < 70:
        letter = 'D+'
    elif percentage >= 60 and percentage < 67:
        letter = 'D'
    elif percentage < 60 and percentage >= 0:
        letter= 'F'
    elif (numeric) < 0:
        print("Score must be between 0 and 10")
    elif (numeric) > 10:
        print("Score must be between 0 and 10")
    elif (scores)== 'done':
         print(percentage,"% and you got an, ",letter)
```

Comment: You need to declare `percentage`, `numeric` and `letter` outside of your loop before using them the way you are trying. Put them in the same place you initialized `grade`, `total`, etc..

Comment: I just did that and it didn't change anything, it still just ends the program when I type done

Comment: You *need* to provide more details on how your program is behaving in a way that does not meet your expectations. Ultimately, you need to provide a better [mcve]

Comment: hey bud, try this notation : `if 0 <= percentage < 60` ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your conditional logic is flawed. You are never assessing the grade (`letter`) if the `score.isdigit()`:

```
while scores != 'done':
    scores=input("Enter Homework score: ")
    if scores.isdigit():
        numeric=int(scores)
        percentage=(numeric*10/count)
        if percentage >= 92 and percentage < 100:
            letter = 'A'
        elif percentage >= 87 and percentage < 92:
            letter = 'B+'
        ...
```

It is often cleaner to jump out of the loop if the initial condition is false, e.g.:

```
while scores != 'done':
    scores=input("Enter Homework score: ")
    if not scores.isdigit():
        continue

    numeric=int(scores)
    percentage=(numeric*10/count)
    if 92 <= percentage < 100:
        letter = 'A'
    elif 87 <= percentage < 92:
        letter = 'B+'
    ...
```

Also in python your shouldn't be afraid of exceptions. A common idiom in python is EAFP (Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission):

```
while scores != 'done':
    scores=input("Enter Homework score: ")
    try:
        numeric = int(scores)
    except ValueError:
        continue
```

You might also want to think about better ways of doing the large grade `if` `elif` `elif` ... block. E.g. an alternative approach would be define a dictionary of the grades:

```
grades = {'A': (92, 100), 'B+': (87, 92)} # Etc..
score = 93
_, letter = max((low <= score < high, letter) for letter, (low, high) in grades.items())
print(letter) # 'A'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should look similar to the one below. Although I still cannot assess the logic behind your program (because you did not explain that in your question, e.g. `percentage=(numeric*10/count)` does not seem quite right to me, etc.), but the code below solves your current problem (based on your current question).

```
grade=""
total=0
count=1
scores=''

percentage = 0

while scores != 'done':
    scores=input("Enter Homework score: ")

    if scores.isdigit():
        numeric=int(scores)

        if numeric < 0:
            print("Score must be between 0 and 10")
        elif numeric > 10:
            print("Score must be between 0 and 10")

        percentage=(numeric*10/count)



if percentage >= 92 and percentage < 100: # I would change this to if percentage >= 92 and percentage <= 100:
    letter = 'A'
elif percentage >= 87 and percentage < 92:
    letter = 'B+'
elif percentage >= 80 and percentage < 87:
    letter = 'B'
elif percentage >=77 and percentage < 80:
    letter = 'C+'
elif percentage >=70 and percentage < 77:
    letter = 'C'
elif percentage >= 67 and percentage < 70:
    letter = 'D+'
elif percentage >= 60 and percentage < 67:
    letter = 'D'
elif percentage < 60 and percentage >= 0:  #I would change this to else:
    letter= 'F'

print(percentage,"% and you got an, ",letter)
```

Comment: I think OP is entering a sequence of scores, this only works for one score.